# How do I store identical arguments to be used by multiple functions

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, arguments

I have multiple functions that will be using the same arguments. Is it possible to store only the arguments into a variable so that I can pass the variable to multiple functions?

Example:

```
#Store the arguments into a variable:
Arguments = (pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
             size_hint=(1, 1), duration=2) #possible?


function1(Arguments) #Then pass variable to first function
function2(Arguments) #Then pass variable to different function
function3(Arguments) #etc.
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the arguments in a dictionary and then use the [`**` unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

```
Arguments = {
    'pos_hint': {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
    'size_hint': (1, 1),
    'duration': 2
}

function1(**Arguments)
function2(**Arguments)
function3(**Arguments)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def func(a, b, c):
...     return a + b + c
...
>>> dct = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> func(**dct)
6
>>>
```

Basically, doing:

```
func(**dct)
```

is equivalent to:

```
func(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Comment: This maybe a bad question but how do I print **dct so I can see the output for myself? and thank you, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean.  The dictionary does not get changed by doing `**dct`.  If you want to see the contents of the dictionary, just do `print dct`.  What output are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Well the input is "'duration':2" but you say the output of unpacking is 'duration = 2'. I just want to see for myself by printing the output when unpacking.

Comment: I do not think what you want is possible.  The `**` syntax is a special tool that tells Python to apply the dictionary to the function's parameters.  There is no "output" in the sense you are thinking of.  Also, the colon `:` is used in the dictionary literal because that is how Python's designers wanted you to assign keys.  You use `=` in function calls though, so that is why it is different.